# Laravel 5: Need to sort a grouped collection by an attribute of first item of each group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection of some Eloquent model items from my database which are grouped by an attribute using `groupBy()`, I need to sort that collection by another attribute of the first item of each group but preserve the initial structure. How can I achieve this, if possible at all?

Comment: you should provide some example data, so that your question becomes clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupBy` returns a collection, so you should still be able to use the `sortBy` method. You need to use a callback to get the attribute value from the first item in each group rather than just giving it a string.

```
$sorted = $groups->sortBy(function ($group, $key) {
    return $group->first()->someAttribute;
});
```